# blank lines in user-defined lists in htlatex

Tags: lists, htlatex

Consider the following latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{list}{*}{}
\item one
\item two
\end{list}
\end{document}
```

It should produce:

- one
- two

But the htlatex output has blank lines before "one" and before "two".

Any ideas about how to fix this?

Also, consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tex4ht}
\begin{document}
\begin{list}{*}{}
\item one
\item two
\end{list}
\end{document}
```

pdflatex outputs blank lines before "one" and "two" plus "xx" before everything.

Comment: what is the intention of `\begin{list}{*}` ? the list environment isn't intended to be used directly in a document, and doesn't take text in its first argument?

Answer (score 2):

Your sample produces blank lines because of how web page works. If you look at generated `html`, you could see:

```xml
<dl class="list1"><dt class="list">
   * </dt><dd 
class="list">
     <!--l. 8--><p class="noindent" >one
     </p></dd><dt class="list">
   * </dt><dd 
class="list">
     <!--l. 10--><p class="noindent" >two</p></dd></dl>
```

`<p>` elements are displayed on standalone lines because this is how they are configured to appear by default. you could use `css` to configure them to be displayed how you want, however better may be to use different way.

For example, using `enumitem` package you may configure lists to display `*` as list item in the `pdf`, and `bullet` in `html`, if I understand correctly that this is what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=$\ast$]
\item one 

\item two
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

`$\ast$` is used insead of `*` as list item, because it has better vertical alignment. When you compile this file with htlatex, this is what you get:

```xml
 <ul class="itemize1">
 <li class="itemize">one
 </li>
 <li class="itemize">two</li></ul>
```

[image]

Regarding your second sample, you shouldn't include `\usepackage{tex4ht}` in your document, it is included automatically with `htlatex`.

Comment: The given code was a sample illustration of the problem. Your answer was not exactly what I needed, but the discovery of the enumitem package has solved my real problem anyway. Thanks.